# Why is my MLP ROC_AUC plotting only 3 points

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, classification, roc, mlp

I am trying to get an ROC curve but my code seem to be plotting a triangle instead. I think I am doing something wrong. I will appreciate any help.

```
model = MLPClassifier()

model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
prediction=model.predict(X_test)

fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(Y_test, prediction)
roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
fpr=array([0.       , 0.2473072, 1.       ])
tpr=array([0.        , 0.70320656, 1.        ])
thresholds=array([2, 1, 0])

# image drawing
plt.figure()
#plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic %d iter' %iter)
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, label = 'MLP AUC = %0.2f' % roc_auc)
plt.legend(loc = 'lower right')
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1],'r--')
plt.xlim([0, 1])
plt.ylim([0, 1])
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.show()
```

Can you please review and suggest what I can do. Even though I am not surprised I have a triangle because if I take a look at my fpr and tpr, there are just 3 values and I do not understand why. I expect to have more values that will result into a curve.

I saw someone has had same challenge as this but the solution did not seem to work for me as I expect the fpr and tpr to return more than 3 values.

Comment: Please keep in mind that SO does not work by simply postig all our code here as-is; code here is supposed to be *minimal* - only the part related with the issue. Here, what's the point of including all this bunch of `print` statements, when neither you show the results nor we can reproduce them without your data (edited our)? Why you don't include at least the values of `fpr`, `tpr`, `thresholds`, which *may* allow us to partially reproduce the issue?

Comment: @desertnaut my bad, this is my first time using SO, I guess I was too anxious to get my question answered, so I did not bother to familiarize myself with the rules.

Comment: Friendly advice: familiarizing yourself with the rules is by far the *safest* way to get your question(s) answered.

Comment: And bring back the plots! As I implied, now that you have provided the `fpr, tpr, thresholds` (which are the only data used there) they may be useful (that's why I didn't edit them out myself).

Comment: @desertnaut sounds good, thanks.